# Use `pandas.to_timedelta` with decimal periods

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta, time-format

In my CSV I have a column with time durations written as `13:08.4` and `13:06.20`.

I would like to convert this column into a pandas timedelta.

However when I try `df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])` I get an error `ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format before .`

What is going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: This answer seems to be very close to what you want: [Convert string to timedelta in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53543307/1609514). Try just changing the `.astype(int)` to `.astype(float)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `'.'` by `':'` like error said to make it in format of `hh:mm:ss`:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].str.replace('.',':'))
#13:08.4 becomes: 0 days 13:08:04
```

OR

If the format of 'Time' is `mm:ss` then use:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:'+df['Time'])
#13:08.4 becomes: 0 days 00:13:08.400000
```